# How to access database from External HDD using mysql (XAMPP) in ubuntu 13.10

Tags: ubuntu, xampp

I have Installed an operating system Ubuntu 13.10 and also installed xampp) and running mysql through XAMPP. but my database file are in External HDD and size is too large so i cannot import this data base and want to access using external HDD only.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I presume that you use phpMyAdmin included in XAMPP. If yes, you can increase phpMyAdmin **Import File Size Limit** in **php.ini** which is located in **...\xampp\php**.

In php.ini file search for **upload_max_filesize** and change the value (2M) to whatever you want (ex: 10M). 2M means 2MB or 2048 Kbytes. Furthermore, search for **post_max_size** and change it from 2M to your custom value (ex: 10M).
After that, save the **php.ini** file and reset Apache and MySQL services. After that you should be able to import your large database.

Set **upload_max_filesize** and **post_max_size** to a bigger size than your database file.